# I'm creating an email application and I don't know what control to use

Tags: c#, winforms

so when the user logs in, the app goes into the inbox page. and the subject and sender of each message would be shown. and when the user selects an email, it opens.
so my question is what control should i use to display the subject and sender?

i was thinking about using labellinks but then each email would have an event for each email (wrong for sure)

I want to use something like a GridView, it is very easy for asp.net websites, but i dont know if the windowsform one could be used the same.

if Gridview is the answer can you show me how to create rows, and how to get the selected row when a user chooses an email?

Answer (score 1):

A (Data)GridView would work.

You can use events like Click or SelectionChanged and values like SelectedRows[ ].

You can create rows manually or bind a DataTable as DataSource (which would be easier to work on).

DataGridView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx
DataTable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx